# How to Start an activity on receiving ACTION_SCREEN_ON message?

Tags: android

I am working on an application which will start an activity on receiving a `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` broadcast message.
How to implement this? Can anyone post the code for it?
I know that I have to use `BroadcastReceiver`. But I need a detailed explanation as I am a beginner.

Comment: In order to get proper support it is best to detail a bit further what you have tried so far and what you have researched on the subject (including code you may have tested). You should not just ask for code. It is not the way Stackoverflow works.

Comment: I will surely do it next time.

Answer (score 0):

Create in your application's AndroidManifest.xml a receiver with a intent-filter to catch android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON:

```
<receiver
    android:name="your.app.packagename.Receiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then, create the receiver class:

```
package your.app.packagename;
// imports here
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action != null && Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON.equals(action)) {
            // Do whatever you need to be done when screen turns on
        }
    }
}
```

Realize that:

- You need launch your app at least one time before it starts receiving the ACTION_SCREEN_ON broadcast.
- The `onReceive()` method is expected to run fast. If you are going to do heavy work, launch an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or a background thread for.